# error at WebChromeClient onProgressChanged event

Tags: java, android, webview

I am creating a app for my blog. I used webview to load the blog site in the main activity. To make it more efficient I used a ProgressBar to do a loading animation when a url loading progress on going. Also add method when capture when another url is called, open it in the system web browser.

This is the code I have trouble with. The problem is when the program captured another url it opens a separate system browser but it keep lagging until I end the app from the Android Studio. Can somebody fix this or do there are any other option for this?

```
webv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            if(!webv.getUrl().startsWith("https://lktechtronic.blogspot.com")){
                webv.stopLoading();
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webv.getUrl())));
                webv.goBack();
            }else if(webv.getUrl().startsWith("https://lktechtronic.blogspot.com")){
                loadinglay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    loadinglay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

- **webv** is the my WebView
- **loadinglay** is the Layout with the ProgressBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may implement shouldOverrideUrlLoading and make your own WebView to load any redirect.